# Using Expressions to combine Funcs with different signature

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I am using the following class to wrap some DocumentDB access which allows me to store multiple entities in the same collection:

```
public class TypedEntity<T> {
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public T Item { get; set; }

    public TypedEntity(T item) {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        Item = item;
        Item.Id = Id;
        Type = typeof (T).FullName;
    } 
}
```

The usage of this class is encapsulated inside a repository class. I'm trying to build the API of the repository class such that the consumer doesn't need to know about the usage of `TypedEntity<T>` and can instead treat it as a source for just `<T>`. For example, the repository has a method with this signature:

```
public async Task<IQueryable<T>> WhereAsync(Func<T, bool> predicate)
```

In order to actually retrieve this data, the predicate needs to be combined/converted with one that interacts with `TypedEntity<T>`. This is the pseudo code that I'm picturing in my head for what I'd ultimately like to achieve:

```
public async Task<IQueryable<T>> WhereAsync(Func<T, bool> predicate) {
    // remembering that dataSource is talking to a backing store of TypedEntity<T>
    var queryable = dataSource.Where(x => x.Type == typeof(T).FullName && predicate(x.Item));
   // ... other business logic stuff
}
```

This actually builds but ultimately results in an Expression that uses .Invoke around the passed in predicate (which DocumentDb is unable to understand). Is there some way that I can combine the type part with the passed in Func to build up the Expression manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to take in an `Expression<>` rather than just a `Func<>`. Then, it should be fairly easy to apply it in a `Where()` clause after you've performed a `Select()` projection:

```
public async Task<IQueryable<T>> WhereAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) {
    // remembering that dataSource is talking to a backing store of TypedEntity<T>
    var typeName = typeof(T).FullName;
    var queryable = dataSource.Where(x => x.Type == typeName)
        .Select(x => x.Item)
        .Where(predicate);
   // ... other business logic stuff
}
```